# Having trouble allowing my play button to be clicked <= 5 times??? Comments in body

Tags: c#

```
namespace Breakout
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //declaring variables
        private int x, y;
        private int xChange, yChange;
        private Graphics canvas;
        private SolidBrush brush;
        private Random randNum;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //creating variables
            canvas = picBoxCanvas.CreateGraphics();
            brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);

            randNum = new Random();
            picBoxCanvas.BackColor = Color.Black;

        }

        private void picBoxCanvas_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Interval = 50;
            timer1.Enabled = true;

            x = randNum.Next(1, picBoxCanvas.Height);
            y = randNum.Next(1, picBoxCanvas.Width);
            xChange = randNum.Next(1, 10); yChange = randNum.Next(1, 10);
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int brushSize;
            x = x + xChange;
            y = y + yChange;
            if (x >= picBoxCanvas.Width)
                xChange = -xChange;

            if (y >= picBoxCanvas.Height)
                yChange = -yChange;

            if (x <= 0)
                xChange = -xChange;

            if (y <= 0)
                yChange = -yChange;

            canvas.Clear(Color.Black);
            brushSize = 15;
            canvas.FillEllipse(brush,  x, y, brushSize, brushSize);


        }

        private void btnCoin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int CoinClick;

            CoinClick =  btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

            for (int count = 0; count <= 5; count++)
            {

            }

        }
    }
}
```

I need the program to run so when  the button coinClick is pressed that starts a count  for the play button which on the 5 time will produce a error(not too fussed about that bit) struggling to delegate the button play
 Any help would be appreciated thank you

Comment: What? You want the `btnPlay_Click` to be called exactly five times? What's the `CoinClick` variable for? And the line below it can't compile, it's a `void`. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: the btnPlay_Click starts a ball bouncing in the canvas. But before the btnPlay_Click is press i want to be able to press the btnCoin to start a counter that only lets the play button presse 5 times or less?? ignore the variable just some thought i had

Comment: @DamonReynolds Don't post irrelevant code, especially code that clearly doesn't even compile.

Comment: @DamonReynolds, I think you'd really benefit from stepping back and looking at how the application should be structured.  There are a lot of examples online that show basic .NET programming implementations that would pay serious dividends here.  Going slow is not a bad thing if the project benefits. /$.02

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so first you need to use the `coin` method as a *reset* for a `private` field:

```
int _playCount;

...

private void btnCoin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _playCount = 5;
}
```

and then, every time the play button is clicked, decrement that count:

```
private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_playCount == 0)
    {
        // maybe alert them; maybe disable the button; whatever...
        return;
    }

    _playCount--;
}
```

Or maybe you just want to disable the button proactively, like this:

```
private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _playCount--;
    btnPlay.Enabled = (_playCount > 0);
}
```

Now, if you disable the button, make sure to enable it in the count reset handler.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your counter outside the method. Each time the method is invoked with a button click it adds.  Have a check to see if the button count is 5, and then deal with it accordingly.

```
private int clickCount;
private void btnCoin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (++clickCount >= 5)
    {
        // Throw error
        clickCount = 0; // reset click count?
    }

}
```